# Laravel relationship manage on multiple columns,

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 tables

> Table-A, Table-B, Table-C, Table-D

Table-B, Table-C, Table-D are master table and in Table-A I have reference_id of other tables.

**Table-A structure**

```
Id           reference_id             content_data                reference_type 
1               1             Test Content related to Table-B       Table-B
2               1             Test Content related to Table-C       Table-C
3               1             Test Content related to Table-D       Table-D
```

**Table-B structure**

```
Id           content_data
1            information of B
```

**Table-C structure**

```
Id           content_data
1            information of C
```

**Table-D structure**

```
Id           content_data
1            information of D
```

I have this type of query and the relationship which will return the Table-A content with the relation of other tables,

```
Table-A::select('*')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->with('Table-B', 'Table-C', 'Table-D')
            ->first();
```

But here I have an issue, when I fetch the data all relationship have the result as all table contains the `id=1` so how to manage this records to get the relationship values which have the `reference_type` field of `Table-A` match?

Comment: i don't think you can have multiple relationships on the same column

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You will get with [Polymorphic Types](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) relationship.

you will get example on [Laravel Polymorphic Relationship](https://appdividend.com/2018/05/18/laravel-polymorphic-relationship-tutorial-example/)